# Batch File To Delete Folders Not Contained In a List

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a group of folders that I would like to keep and would like to delete the rest.  I have a .txt file that contains the names of the folders that I would like to keep.

So here is what I have:

In `C:\test` I have the following folders:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
```

In my text file `exclude.txt` I have listed the following folder names:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

Thus, I would like my end product to be that `C:\test` should only have the folders `AAA`, `BBB`, and `CCC` after the batch file.

Here is what I have so far but not having any luck:

```
for /d %%a in ("C:\test\*") do findstr /i /x /c:"%%~nxa" exclude.txt || rd /s /q %%a
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're pretty close. The following works for me... (just added a '\' character to your directory name)

```
for /d %%a in ("C:\test\*") do findstr /i /x /c:"%%~nxa" exclude.txt || rd /s /q %%a
```

Comment: For some reason it is only picking up the first line from my text file. From my example above, it will delete all files except AAA. Do I have to rearrange the text file or change the batch coding somehow?  Also do I need to specify the full location of exclude.txt? or just the shortened path?

Comment: You will need to have exclude.txt in the same path as your batch file or provide a full path to it. It will show something like `FINDSTR: Cannot open exclude.txt` if it can't find it (and it will delete ALL the directories, so be careful).

Comment: If you need to, just test each part of the command to see if it is running as you would expect.

Comment: Checked everything and it all looked good.  Still not getting the desired results.  Not sure where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as the guy above that it was only working for the first line in my exclusion file.

after a while i realised it was atually just not wokring for the last line in my exclusion list but because i was testing it with only 2 lines i couldnt tell the difference.

when i put real data in with 84 exclusions i realise what was happening and my workaround was to put a dummy exclusion at the end of the file, knowing it gets ignored anyway

Comment: probably you had no LineEnding at the last line. `Findstr` has problems with that.